# How to create a currying function similar to how dispatch is used in react readux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, currying

I need to preface this by saying the following code is just simple code for easy demonstration.  But I am trying to make a currying function (or at least I think thats what its called) in plain js (no react) similar to how react/redux uses dispatch like this:

```
const action = (val) => (dispatch) => {
  // The function can now use val and dispatch
}
```

I am passing multiple functions into a associating function that will add a state value and a setState value and I am hoping to be able to use the function like so:

```
const action = (val) => (state, setState) => {
  // the function can now use val, state, and setState
}

action('foo');
```

The associating function currently looks like the following:

```
const action1 = (val) => {
  setState(val);
};

const action2 = (val) => {
  setState(val);
};

const associateActions = (actions) => {
  const associated = {};
  Object.keys(actions).forEach((key) => {
    associated[key] = function (...args) {
      actions[key](...args, state, setState);
    };
  });
  return associated;
};

const associatedActions = associateActions({ action1, action2 });
```

But I want to be able to pass the state and setState to the actions like so:

```
const action1 = (val) => (state, setState) => {
  setState(val);
};

const action2 = (val) => (state, setState) => {
  setState(val);
};
```

I can easily just add the state and setState functions to the end like so `(...args, state, setState)` but it seems like it can get confusing having them appended to the end like that so I would like to figure out how to write them in a tailing currying function but am unable to figure out how to do so.

Here is a jsFiddle to play with [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/gm15xvnu/)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean something like `actions[key](...args)(state,setState);`?

Comment: have a look at this article:
https://medium.com/javascript-scene/curry-and-function-composition-2c208d774983

Comment: @c0m1t yes that worked I though I was on the right track but I was a bit confused.  `actions[key](...args)(state,setState);` this works though thanks!

Comment: @user3331344 Yes for example your `action1` function is a function which returns a function, so after calling it by `val`, you would get another function, which you can call it by `state` and `setState`.